# Bug in Mapbox Dataset Editor – moving linestring points freezes editor

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

When I try to adjust the points on a linestring in Dataset Editor, the editor partially freezes – the points don't move and I can't deselect the linestring, but undo still works. Please watch video:

https://www.loom.com/share/3a29ad687dac43069a092f6edadd2c27

Technically, the points do move – if I save and then reload the editor, the points are in the new positions. But as seen in video, the Editor fails to show visual confirmation, without reloading the page.

Info regarding this dataset:

In addition to this and other linestrings, this dataset contains polygons and individual points, which do not suffer from this bug. The dataset is only 181 kb with 200 features.

Also this linestring has 3 other linestrings with identical points at this location. I can select, copy, delete any of these 4 identical linestrings using the Search Dataset function, and I can shift the entire linestring – but they all freeze when trying to adjust the points.

After reload I can sometimes move 1 point of 1 linestring 1 time, but the 2nd instance causes the bug.

This bug exists on Chrome, Safari and Firefox on my Mac.

Is there a suggested workaround?

Thank you for your help

-Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset has a lot of linestrings hundreds of points (e.g. roadways), Mapbox Dataset Editor will freeze if you try to shift any points.

So now I'm using JOSM which is good – its a more powerful desktop app for editing geoJSON files